# SharpSVN connection issues in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, svn

I have the following code to access SVN using SharpSVN

```
 AddHandler SVNclient.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers, Sub(ssender As Object, ev As SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs)
                                                                        ev.AcceptedFailures = ev.Failures
                                                                        ev.Save = True
                                                                    End Sub

SVNclient.Authentication.ForceCredentials("user", "password")
```

When I execute locally, I have no issues. When I deploy it to our test server, I get the following error

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://....'
```

I am able to connect to the repo using TortoiseSVN  on the server.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this? I would prefer to NOT have to force credentials if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
      svnClient.LoadConfiguration(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Svn"), True)
      svnClient.Authentication.Clear()

      AddHandler svnClient.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers, Sub(ssender As Object, ev As SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs)
                                                                                        ev.AcceptedFailures = ev.Failures
                                                                                        ev.Save = True
                                                                                    End Sub

      svnClient.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
```